# How do make sure that a property is defined and a method is defined

Tags: facebook, selenium, webdriver, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently trying to write tests with the facebook webdriver.  I'm trying to use selectByValue, but I get the error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method RemoteWebElement::selectByValue()"

Here's the current snippet

```
 $selectClickButtonfirst = $this
     ->webDriver
     ->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('resultsPerPage'));
 $selectOptions = $selectClickButtonfirst->findElement(
     WebDriverBy::tagName('option')
 );
 $selectOptions->selectByValue('5')->click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [`WebDriverElement`](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/lib/WebDriverElement.php) which is returned by method `findElement()` has no such abilities.

If you want to use `selectByValue` to select an `<option>` inside `<select>` you have to construct a `WebDriverSelect` passing target instance of `WebDriverElement` as an argument. You can see [construction](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/tests/functional/WebDriverSelectTest.php#L40) and [usage](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/tests/functional/WebDriverSelectTest.php#L161) in test files.

I believe finally code should look smth like:

```
$selectClickButtonfirst = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('resultsPerPage'));
$select = new WebDriverSelect($selectClickButtonFirst); // assuming previous returns <select>
$select->selectByValue('5');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked.  I really appreciate you explanation.  "That's because WebDriverElement which is returned by method findElement() has no such abilities."